# jQuery add - to input but only add twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this little script here... It adds a "-" after every 4 characters but i need it to not add the - after the 12 character.

```
$(function(){
$("#promo").keyup(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ((($this.val().length+1) % 5)==0){
        $this.val($this.val() + "-");
        }   
    });        
});
```

But it is adding a "-" at the end of the 12 characters despite my character limit of 14.

i have a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sAu32/)

How would i prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`maxlength` attribute does not prevent you to modify `<input>` value using Javascript.

You can still add a check:

```
$(function(){
    $("#promo").keyup(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ((($this.val().length+1) % 5)==0 && $this.val().length() < $this.attr("maxlength")){
      $this.val($this.val() + "-");
    }   
  });        
});
```

Comment: Wow, just made this in Fiddle, too.  Man, there are just too many helpful people on this site!  Ha!

Comment: thanks @GuillaumePoussel! my jQuery and JS is still very basic!

Comment: Sorry it took them a minute to allow me to do that... @GuillaumePoussel

Answer (score 1):

You could add this inside your if:

```
if ($this.val().length > 12) {
    return false;
}
```

Code suggestion (with less jQuery):

```
$(function () {
    $("#promo").keyup(function () {
        if (((this.value.length + 1) % 5) == 0) {
            if (this.value.length > 12) {
                return false;
            }
            this.value += "-";
        }
    });
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dKemJ/)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the && AND operator and make it a condition that nothing will happen if val.length is greater 11

```
$(function(){
    $("#promo").keyup(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ((($this.val().length+1) % 5)==0 && $this.val().length <=11){
            $this.val($this.val() + "-");
            }   
        });        
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sAu32/3/

Answer (score 0):

I did not look at fiddle but;

```
$(function(){
    $("#promo").keyup(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ((($this.val().length+1) % 5)==0 && $this.val().length <= 12){
        $this.val($this.val() + "-");
        }   
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("#promo").keyup(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.val().length<14){
        if ((($this.val().length+1) % 5)==0){
            $this.val($this.val() + "-");
            }   
        }
        });        
    });
```

There you go.

And the Fiddle update [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sAu32/2/)